# WindowsFormsHost control not displaying in Prism Region

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, windowsformshost, windowsformsintegration

I am using the pdf viewer on this link

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfpdfviewer

It is displayed properly in the window and everything works as expected.
But when I added my view to region, it not displaying, other user components in my view displaying correctly, only PdfViewer not displaying.

I prepared a sample code that outlines this scenario.

> Here is PdfViewer Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Akbank.Treasury.Client.WPF.Controls.PdfViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Akbank.Treasury.Client.WPF.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="pdfControl"
             d:DesignHeight="500"
             d:DesignWidth="900">

    <Grid>

        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="pdfHost">
            <local:WinFormPdfHost>

            </local:WinFormPdfHost>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> And this is My View

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Treasury.Common.Views.Common.Document.DocumentView"
                 xmlns:TControls="clr-namespace:Akbank.Treasury.Client.WPF.Controls;assembly=Akbank.Treasury.Client.WPF.Controls"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <Label Content="some content" />
            <TextBox Text="some content" />
            <TControls:PdfViewer Width="500"
                                 Height="500"
                                 x:Name="pdfViewer" />
        </StackPanel>

    </UserControl>
```

> This works

```
        Window window = new Window();
        window.Content = myView;
        window.Show();
```

> This does not work, other components displaying but Pdf control not displaying.

```
        RegionManager.AddToRegion("MainRegion", myView);
```

Comment: This is surely the infamous "airspace problem".  WindowsFormsHost needs to provide a window to host the winforms control.  That has sharp edges, layering can no longer work correctly.  Googling "windowsformshost airspace issue" can provide you with good background info about this problem.  You probably need to go shopping for a PDF viewer control that is friendlier to WPF and uses the WPF rendering model.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Visual Studio's Output window while debugging?

Comment: @dymanoid There is no any output error

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your answer. I already buy Telerik wpf components but RadPdfViewer not displaying some pdf documents as expected. This component(WindowsFormsPdfHost) very well but I am disappointed to be incompatible with the region

Comment: @HansPassant this answer was very valuable. Thanks again.